# Problem with maven and spring boot: null returned by binding at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spock

I'm trying to run maven commands on spring boot project but all the time I'm getting a lot of errors like this:

```
22) null returned by binding at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
 but parameter 0 of org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.<init>() is not @Nullable
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.RepositoryEventDispatcher
    for parameter 0 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.<init>(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:103)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.MetadataResolver
    for parameter 0 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.<init>(DefaultVersionResolver.java:111)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
    for parameter 1 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.<init>(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:116)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactDescriptorReader
    for parameter 1 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.<init>(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:92)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.DependencyCollector
    for parameter 5 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:121)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingHelper
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder
  while locating org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.Maven
```

While running in Intellij on Windows there is no problem. The problem is when I'm trying to run it from command line on linux. On the both devices is the same version of maven.

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tatara</groupId>
    <artifactId>Euress</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Euress</name>
    <description>Euress application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <groovy.version>2.1.5</groovy.version>
        <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.6</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
        <spock-spring.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock-spring.version>
        <cglib-nodep.version>3.2.7</cglib-nodep.version>
        <groovy-all.version>2.4.4</groovy-all.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy-all.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib-nodep.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock-spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Maybe someone could help me to find any solution for that problem ? I think it could be something with spock and maven versions.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot build your project and see the same error because I only have a POM. But I can look at your POM and see

```xml
<groovy.version>2.1.5</groovy.version>
<groovy-all.version>2.4.4</groovy-all.version>
```

You do not use `groovy.version` directly, but probably in one of the dependency POMs this property is used because when I look at the effective POM via `mvn help:effective-pom`, I see this:

```xml
<!-- (...) -->

    <groovy-all.version>2.4.4</groovy-all.version>
    <groovy.version>2.1.5</groovy.version>

<!-- (...) -->

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>2.
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-ant</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- and many more modules like these -->
```

Then I see that Spock-Spring 1.1-groovy-2.4 actually prefers Groovy 2.4.9, so we are dealing with yet another version here, we already have

- 2.1.5 - definitely too old, why would you use Groovy 2.1 for a Spock version designed for Groovy 2.4?
- 2.4.4
- 2.4.9

Then in your effective POM there also is a transitive dependency

```xml
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

which again references the property you are overriding and a newer Spock and Groovy version:

```xml
    <properties>
        <groovy.version>2.5.7</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>1.3-groovy-2.5</spock.version>
    </properties>

<!-- (...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And this is where your version conflict comes from. I suggest you define which Groovy and Spock versions you want in your own POM (or parent POM) in a `dependencyManagement` section, later only importing the actual dependencies without version numbers in the `dependencies` section. And while you are at it, you could also upgrade to Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5 and a Groovy 2.5 version. Shall we?

Besides, you are not even directly referencing Spock Core, it is only a transitive dependency of Spock Spring. Maybe you want to include the direct dependency too because it is kind of important for your testing, is it not?

I am keeping your Groovy-All import, but you might consider just to import the Groovy modules you really need for testing, minimally just `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy`.

See if this works for you:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.tatara</groupId>
  <artifactId>Euress</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Euress</name>
  <description>Euress application</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <groovy.version>2.5.8</groovy.version>
    <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.8.1</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
    <spock.version>1.3-groovy-2.5</spock.version>
    <cglib-nodep.version>3.2.7</cglib-nodep.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- Manage your versions here, i.e. fixing them for your project, even if your imported POMs disagree -->
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib-nodep.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <!-- Import the dependencies you need here, the versions and default scopes have already be managed above -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/groovy</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
              </includes>
            </source>
          </sources>
          <testSources>
            <testSource>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
              </includes>
            </testSource>
          </testSources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation of problem with dependency versions. Unfortunately the pom file from your answer doesn't work but I found that the problem apperas even with empty maven project. So it's problem with device or environment, not with application.

Comment: The POM works for me, I created a sample Spring Boot application (so I get past the repackage error) and a Spock test (so as to see if Maven executes the test and IntelliJ IDEA activates Spock), both work flawlessly. Maybe you did not copy 100% of my POM or you have a problem with the local Maven repository (or a company repository sever such as Nexus or Artifactory) in your environment. So I agree it must be something in your environment. Still your POM was kind of a mess and ought to be cleaned up if you don't want artifact version resolution to be a lottery.

Comment: One more idea: You did not mention your Maven version. I tried with 3.6.3 (bundled with IDEA) and 3.6.0 (local installation), both work nicely. JDK 1.8.0_211 or 13.0.1, also both fine.

Comment: I said and begining that problem occurs only on linux. My version of POM and Your works fine on windows. The problem is on device with linux but i found out that the problem is even with empty maven project, so the problem is not with project but with environment.

Comment: Again: Which Maven and JDK versions are you using on Linux? Is there any difference to Windows? Which repository manager do you use? I have found several problems with both Maven and Nexus with similar stack traces as yours, thus the question.

Comment: Maven: 3.3.9, JDK: 1.8.0_252, OS: Raspbian 9. Whot do you mean by repository manager ? Isn't maven enoug ?

Comment: Can you please try with Maven 3.6.x just to be on par with my version here? Raspbian, aha. That's not a desktop Linux, I do not have any experience Raspberry stuff, only a few years ago embedded Linux for my DSL + router device Fritz!Box (popular in Germany). If you don't know what a repository manager is, never mind. I was under the impression you were working on a commercial project in a company behind a repository manager, as usual in enterprise environments. Of course a local Maven repo should be okay for private projects.